# How push returned value into array with multiple asynchronous await calls in foreach loop

Tags: node.js

I want to make multiple asynchronous await function calls in a forEach loop and push the returned value into an array. But it returns a promise. How can I store the actual returned value in the array? Thanks for the help.

```
let table1Assignments = [];
        await groupingTable1Id.forEach(table1Id => {(
             table1Assignments.push(assignmentsDAO.getAssignmentsOfTable(table1Id, date, time)))
        });
```

getAssignmentsOfTable looks like this:

```
 async getAssignmentsOfTable(tableId, date = null) {
   let stmt =
      `SELECT * 
       FROM assignment a
       WHERE a.dining_table_id = $1` + (date?' AND a.date = $2':'');
    const params = date?[tableId, date]:[tableId];

    const result = await this.db.query(stmt, params);

    return result.rows.map(row => {
        return new Assignment(
          row.id,
          row.dining_table_id,
          row.guest_group_id,
          row.date,
          row.time
        );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would follow this pattern:

```
Promise.all([
  groupingTable1Id.map(table1Id => assignmentsDAO.getAssignmentsOfTable(table1Id, date, time))
]).then((table1Assignments) => {
  table1Assignments.forEach(assignment) { process(assignment) });
});
```

See documentation about JavaScript (ES6) *Promise.all* [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to group your promises under one big promise. It looks like this

```
const promises = Promise.all(
  // map your IDs to assignment promises
  groupingTable1Id.map(table1Id => assignmentsDAO
    .getAssignmentsOfTable(table1Id, date, time))
);

promises.then(table1Assignments => {
  // Do stuff with assignments
  table1Assignments.forEach(console.log);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `forEach`, you can use `for of` loop, like this:

```
let table1Assignments = [];
for (const table1Id of groupingTable1Id) {
  table1Assignments.push(await assignmentsDAO.getAssignmentsOfTable(...));
}
```

Edit: This is not fastest solution in terms of performance because of the sequential execution compared to `Promise.all`, but I find it clearer.

Comment: This is non-optimal since each iteration needs to wait for the previous one to finish. [Marco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54518115/1814486)'s answer uses a more efficient approach.

Comment: True, although if optimization is what you need, you would go for a `for` loop instead of `.map` method. But I agree if you you have no issue with each iteration being executed in parallel, `Promise.all` is faster. But I think my way is clearer and easier to understand.

Comment: That's comparing apples and oranges. Here you're doing *sequential async* work. `Promise.all` *parallelises* that work. The performance benefits you can get from parallel async work are potentially huge.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I said: _if you have no issue with each iteration being executed in parallel, Promise.all is faster_

Comment: I was mostly replying to your `although if optimization is what you need, you would go for a for loop instead of .map method` line. This is a micro-optimisation. Parallel async work is not though.

Comment: Oh yes, `Promise.all` is no doubt faster. I am just suggesting another option which I think has merits of its own. I added a little disclaimer at the end of my answer to address this.